# Why did the Chronicoms not interfere previously?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

The Chronicoms have stated that they are meant only to observe, with the sole exception being when humanity is threatened with “an extinction-level event.” This apparently need not be an event that actually renders humans extinct, as we see from the event in question.

Obviously, this explains why they didn’t care much about Hydra, or Aida, or Hela, or Kilgrave, or whoever, or with the internal conflicts of Inhumans, S.H.I.E.L.D., or indeed any regular human organizations.

But why, then, did they not interfere when:

- The Chitauri invaded Earth?
- Hive sought to turn all humans into Inhumans and make them extensions of itself?
- Dormammu tried to consume the planet?
- Ultron tried to drop a  city on the planet?

Were they unaware? Unable? Did these not meet their criteria? Did they try and fail?

Comment: There may be a matter of timing: both the Chitauri invasion and Ultron's attack happened in a matter of days. Maybe no time to react properly. (I don't watch Agent of SHIELD)

Comment: Their agents are "permitted" to intervene. That doesn't mean they have to. And clearly humanity didn't become extinct from these events, so they didn't even need to.

Comment: It appears that the Chronicoms have some ability to predict the future, as Enoch was able to know to send SHIELD into the future in Season 4's finale. If they saw that Earth's heroes would be able to stop these threats by themselves, then there would be no need to intervene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, great question. Seems like if Chronicoms are really supposed to protect humanity from extinction-level threats we would've heard of them before. The fact that there is so little information on them makes it even harder to answer your question. However, here's my take on it:

- The Chronicoms didn't interfere when the Chitauri invaded Earth because the Chitauri weren't trying to massacre humanity. They were instead trying to enslave it. If this is the case (and it's possible I'm wrong here), then that would explain why the Chronicoms didn't act.
- Hive's mission to take over the planet and turn humans into inhumans is harder to answer. The only reasons I can come up with are that they calculated that he would not be able to accomplish his mission, they were waiting until it was proven to be a possible threat to humanity's survival, or they consider inhumans an offshoot of humans. If they considered inhumans to be humans technically, then it wouldn't qualify as an extinction-level event.
- Dormammu is another tough one, but from what I remember, he was trying to basically move Earth into the Dark Dimension, where (according to the comics) it shouldn't be destroyed, but would rather just meld with other dimensions. This would cause a lot of harm, but I don't think it would exterminate humanity. Maybe this is why the Chronicoms didn't interfere.
- Finally, it seems like Ultron dropping a city back down to Earth wouldn't exterminate humanity (correct me if I'm wrong here; it's been a while since I saw Avengers 2), so again maybe this is why the Chronicoms didn't interfere.

Do you think that's plausible? There's also the possibility that Chronicoms hadn't been introduced yet to the MCU at the time of these events, so the writers just didn't include them for that reason, even though realistically we should've seen them. But honestly that's a pretty unsatisfactory answer.